# Lighthouse Node JS module not returning result

Tags: javascript, node.js, lighthouse

I am using lighthouse programmatically using Node JS. Previously managed to get the results but now I can't seemed to get the results. Checked the port and noticed the website is opened in but lighthouse is not running.

Chrome Launcher version is "^0.10.2", Lighthouse version is ^2.8.0

```
"use strict";

const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

function launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(url, flags = {}, config = null) {
return chromeLauncher.launch(flags).then(chrome => {
    flags.port = chrome.port;
    console.log(chrome.port);
    return lighthouse(url, flags, config).then(results =>
        chrome.kill().then(() => results));
});
}

const flags = {
 chromeFlags: ['disable-gpu','--headless']
};

launchChromeAndRunLighthouse('https://github.com', flags).then(results => {
fs.appendFile('result.txt', JSON.stringify(results), (err) => {
    console.log('error appending to file example.txt');
});
});
```

Comment: Was anything different about your code when it was working previously? Are you running this locally? What platform are you on? I think we need more information.

In my experience working with lighthouse it was easy to get it up and running locally but deploying it require a lot of other steps and considerations that had nothing to do with my code.

Comment: There was no change in my code. Yes I am running locally. The problem started to occur when I updated the lighthouse version. When I created a copy of my old code and run it with previous version of lighthouse, the problem doesn't occur. But when I update the node modules and run the same code the problem occurs.